# Wrong Path in Startup.Configure

Tags: asp.net-core

I'm creating an ASP.Net Core WebApp which I publish to a web hosting. When I start the application (*call the page*) I always get the error: An error occurred while starting the application.

In the log I found the follow exception:

at Paragliding.Startup.Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env) in C:\Users\buhli\source\repos\Paragliding\Paragliding\Startup.cs:line 76

The Path: "C:\User\buhli..." is the path from my local computer and I have to replace this with the path form the web hosting.

Unfourtnely I can't find this path in my project. Can somebody help me here and tell me form were exaclty comes this path and where I can change it?

Thank you very much

Edit - full exceptions:

Application startup exception: System.ArgumentException: Keyword not supported: 'userid'.
....
   at Paragliding.Startup.Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env) in C:\Users\buhli\source\repos\Paragliding\Paragliding\Startup.cs:line 76
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.ConventionBasedStartup.Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration.IISSetupFilter.<>c__DisplayClass4_0.b__0(IApplicationBuilder app)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.HostFilteringStartupFilter.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.b__0(IApplicationBuilder app)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.AutoRequestServicesStartupFilter.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.b__0(IApplicationBuilder builder)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost.BuildApplication()
crit: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost[6]
      Application startup exception
...
   at Paragliding.Startup.Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env) in C:\Users\buhli\source\repos\Paragliding\Paragliding\Startup.cs:line 76
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---

Comment: Share full exception details

Comment: @Mohammad Barbast I added the full exception